# Javascript not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I added a custom jquery function to my wordpress site. The code was to open a popup window on every alternative clicks. This doesn't work if I add to my wordpress theme `header.php`
This is what I added `<script src="/alternateclicks.js"></script>`
The js file was added to the wordpress root location `public_html`. I don't see any popup whatsoever.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
var canClick = 2;
$("body").click(function () {
    if (canClick%2==0) {
        window.open("https://example.com/").blur();
        window.focus();
        canClick = canClick+1;
    }
else {
canClick=canClick+1;}
});
});
```

The solutions I tried, I tried adding the code to `footer.php`. Didn't work. I added them using `wp_enqueue`. Didn't work.

**UPDATE**
In console am seeing that jquery is not defined. But I added the code only in footer.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: you should add javascript code in the footer and if you're adding in the header then make sure you add it after `wp_head()` so that `jquery` loads first and then your script loads. although, you should use wordpress enqueue functions to properly register and enqueue your scripts and styles.

Comment: I tried `wp_enqueue` , added the code to the footer, doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, a Plugin interfered with my loading. The plugin disabled jquery.
Found that the code worked in some pages and didn't work in some pages.
Found out using the console.
Then later when disabling the plugin perfmatters, jquery worked fine.